# Open source firewall as a virtual appliance?

Tags: firewall, virtual-machines

Is it possible to have an open source firewall which can run as a virtual appliance into a guest VM where all traffic from the other VMs should go through this firewall VM?
And it supports also routing and NAT functions?
Any thoughts or advise are welcome.

Comment: I have done my best to respect the clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org), it satisfies all your requirements.